# Who to load dropdown options from API in react JS with typescript and react saga?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, redux-saga

Here is my [page](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cruz94/58f92e14deaef7529f61997c7fe3c6ee/raw/6f8a610d589bdbd1970a29e45bebfc2346cd64b0/AddLaunchDialog.tsx), Here I want to load brand option from API.
I have written saga attached below:

Action.tsx

```
 export const getBrandsForDropdown = (request: IPagination) => {
      return {
        type: actions,
        payload: request
      }
    }
```

Api.tsx

```
export const getBrandsForDropdown = async () => {
  const page = 1;
  const limit = 1000;
  console.log("get brand drop down");
  const query = `user/master/brands?page=${page}&limit=${limit}`;
  return client(query, { body: null }).then(
    (data) => {
      console.log("get brand drop down in ");
      return { data, error: null };
    },
    (error) => {
      return { data: null, error };
    }
  );
};
```

Reducer.ts

```
case actions.GET_BRANDS_DROPDOWN_PENDING:
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: true,
  };
case actions.GET_BRANDS_DROPDOWN_REJECTED:
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
  };
case actions.GET_BRANDS_DROPDOWN_RESOLVED:
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    brandOptions: action.payload,
  };
```

Saga.ts

```
function* getBrandForDropDownSaga(action: HandleGetBrandsForDropdown) {
    yield put(switchGlobalLoader(true));

    yield put(pendingViewBrand());
    try {
        const { data } = yield getBrandsForDropdown();

        yield put(resolvedViewBrand(data));
        yield put(switchGlobalLoader(false));
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(switchGlobalLoader(false));
        return;
    }
}
```

After this I don't how to call it in my page and get it as a options in brand dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Original Answer: Just Use Thunk

You can do this with `redux-saga` but I wouldn't recommend it.  `redux-thunk` is a lot easier to use.  Thunk is also built in to `@reduxjs/toolkit` which makes it even easier.

There is no need for an `IPagination` argument because you are always setting the pagination to `{page: 1, limit: 1000}`

Try something like this:

```
import {
  createAsyncThunk,
  createSlice,
  SerializedError
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { IDropdownOption } from "office-ui-fabric-react";
import client from ???

// thunk action creator
export const fetchBrandsForDropdown = createAsyncThunk(
  "fetchBrandsForDropdown",
  async (): Promise<IDropdownOption[]> => {
    const query = `user/master/brands?page=1&limit=1000`;
    return client(query, { body: null });
    // don't catch errors here, let them be thrown
  }
);

interface State {
  brandOptions: {
    data: IDropdownOption[];
    error: null | SerializedError;
  };
  // can have other properties
}

const initialState: State = {
  brandOptions: {
    data: [],
    error: null
  }
};

const slice = createSlice({
  name: "someName",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // could add any other case reducers here
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) =>
    builder
      // handle the response from your API by updating the state
      .addCase(fetchBrandsForDropdown.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.brandOptions.data = action.payload;
        state.brandOptions.error = null;
      })
      // handle errors
      .addCase(fetchBrandsForDropdown.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.brandOptions.error = action.error;
      })
});

export default slice.reducer;
```

In your component, kill the `brandOptions` state and access it from Redux.  Load the options when the component mounts with a `useEffect`.

```
const brandOptions = useSelector((state) => state.brandOptions.data);

const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(fetchBrandsForDropdown());
}, [dispatch]);
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-fetch-brand-options-3e114?file=/src/components/App.tsx)

#### Updated: With Saga

The general idea of how to write the saga is correct in your code.

1. `take` the parent asynchronous action.
2. `put` a pending action.
3. `call` the API to get data.
4. `put` a resolved action with the data or a rejected action with an error.

The biggest mistakes that I'm seeing in your saga are:

- Catching errors upstream.
- Mismatched data types.
- Not wrapping API functions in a `call` effect.

**Error Handling**

Your `brands.api` functions are all catching their API errors which means that the `Promise` will always be resolved.  The `try`/`catch` in your saga won't have errors to catch.

If you want to `catch` the errors in the saga then you need to remove the `catch` from the functions `getBrandsForDropdown` etc.  You can just return the data directly rather than mapping to `{ result: data, error: null }`.  So delete the whole `then` function.  I recommend this approach.

```
export const getBrandsForDropdown = async () => {
  const page = 1;
  const limit = 1000;

  const query = `user/master/brands?page=${page}&limit=${limit}`;
  return client(query, { body: null });
}
```

If you want to keep the current structure of returning a `{ result, error }` object from all API calls then you need to modify the saga to look for an error in the function return.

```
function* getBrandForDropDownSaga() {
  yield put(switchGlobalLoader(true));

  yield put(pendingGetBrands());
  const { data, error } = yield call(getBrandsForDropdown);
  if (error) {
    yield put(rejectedGetBrands(error.message));
  } else {
    yield put(resolvedGetBrands(data));
  }
  yield put(switchGlobalLoader(false));
}
```

**Mismatched Data Types**

There's some type mismatching in your reducer and state that you need to address.  In some places you are using an array `IBrand[]` and in others you are using an object `{ results: IBrand[]; totalItems: number; currentPage: string; }`.  If you add the return type `IState` to the reducer then you'll see.

There's also a mismatch between a single `IBrand` and an array.  I don't know the exact shape of your API response, but `getBrandsForDropdown` definitely has an `array` of brands somewhere.  Your saga `getBrandForDropDownSaga` is dispatching `resolvedViewBrand(data)` which takes a single `IBrand` instead of `resolvedGetBrands(data)` which takes an array `IBrand[]`.  If you add return types to the functions in your `brands.api` file then you'll see these mistakes highlighted by Typescript.

**Don't Repeat Yourself**

You can do a lot of combining in your API and your saga between the `getBrands` and the `getBrandsForDropdown`.  Getting the brands for the dropdown is just a specific case of `getBrands` where you set certain arguments: `{ page: 1, limit: 1000 }`.

```
export interface IPagination {
  page?: number;
  limit?: number;
  sort?: "ASC" | "DESC";
  column?: string;
}
```

```
export const getBrands = async (request: IPagination): Promise<IBrands> => {
  const res = await axios.get<IBrands>('/user/master/brands', {
    params: request,
  });
  return res.data;
};
```

```
function* coreGetBrandsSaga(request: IPagination) {
  yield put(switchGlobalLoader(true));
  yield put(pendingGetBrands());
  try {
    const data = yield call(getBrands, request);
    yield put(resolvedGetBrands(data));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(rejectedGetBrands(error?.message));
  }
  yield put(switchGlobalLoader(false));
}
```

```
function* getBrandsSaga(action: HandleGetBrands) {
  const { sort } = action.payload;
  if ( sort ) {
    yield put(setSortBrands(sort));
    // what about column?
  }
  const brandsState = yield select((state: AppState) => state.brands);

  const request = {
    // defaults
    page: 1,
    limit: brandsState.rowsPerPage,
    column: brandsState.column,
    // override with action
    ...action.payload,
  }

  // the general function can handle the rest
  yield coreGetBrandsSaga(request);
}
```

```
function* getBrandsForDropDownSaga() {
  // handle by the general function, but set certain the request arguments
  yield coreGetBrandsSaga({
    page: 1,
    limit: 1000,
    sort: "ASC",
    column: "name",
  })
}
```

```
export default function* brandsSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(HANDLE_GET_BRANDS, getBrandsSaga);
  yield takeLatest(GET_BRANDS_DROPDOWN, getBrandForDropDownSaga);
  ...
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/saga-fetch-brand-options-xi70v?file=/src/store/brands/saga.ts)

Comment: it works, but I cant use thunk here. Im looking for a solution with saga :(

Comment: Do you currently have a reducer?  A root saga?  Can you share that code?  I’m fully capable of writing this in saga but I don’t want to rewrite your whole app.

Comment: Hi, I have added my files here, thank you for helping https://github.com/cruz94/brands_fl